# Library mismatch (quartz, activiti-engine, usertype.jodatime, grails-shiro)

Tags: grails, jodatime, activiti, shiro, quartz

I am testing my old BuildConfig configuration from grails version 2.5.6 to build.gradle from grails version 4.0.1.
For that I try to generate a test application where I'm just setting up build.gradle and nothing more.
In the dependencies section I have:

```
// My customizations

compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

// JodaTime
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jadira.usertype/usertype.core
compile 'org.joda:joda-money:1.0.1'
compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.5'
compile group: 'org.jadira.usertype', name: 'usertype.jodatime', version: '2.0.1'

// Activiti BPM

compile group: 'org.activiti.core.common', name: 'activiti-project-model', version: '7.1.0.M5'
compile group: 'org.activiti.api', name: 'activiti-api-runtime-shared', version: '7.1.0.M5'
compile group: 'org.activiti', name: 'activiti-process-validation', version: '7.1.0.M5'
compile group: 'org.activiti', name: 'activiti-bpmn-model', version: '7.1.0.M5'
compile group: 'org.activiti', name: 'activiti-bpmn-converter', version: '7.1.0.M5'
compile group: 'org.activiti', name: 'activiti-engine', version: '7.1.0.M5'

// Quartz
compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.3.2'

// Shiro
compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'grails-shiro',  version:'4.2'
```

With this configuration above we get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -XX:CICompilerCount=3 -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath2104238730.jar org.grails.cli.GrailsCli run-app --plain-output
|Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...
CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 8s
|Running application...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe''
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 14s
Error |
Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

The application runs perfectly if, for example, we delete one (only one) from the following libraries: quartz, usertype.jodatime, grails-shiro, activiti-engine
That is, these libraries do not all work together, I need to remove some of them for the application to run.
Could you shed some light on this issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: First of all, i'd run with `--stacktrace` to actually see the error.  Next check the dependency report from gradle and check especially the things pulled in from the libs you already figured out to have some relation to the problem.

Comment: I ran the application with grails run-app --stacktrace --verbose, but the error message is not clear to me: ... Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\testeGrails"): ...

Comment: Can you include the full log output in your question?